# How to more efficiently calculate a rolling ratio

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, iteration

1. i have data length is over 3000.
2. below are code for making 20days value ( Volume Ration in Stock market)
3. it took more than 2 min.
4. is there any good way to reduce running time.

   ```
   import pandas as pd
   import numpy as np
   from pandas.io.data import DataReader
   import matplotlib.pylab as plt
   data = DataReader('047040.KS','yahoo',start='2010')
     data['vr']=0
     data['Volume Ratio']=0
     data['acend']=0
    data['vr'] = np.sign(data['Close']-data['Open']) 
    data['vr'] = np.where(data['vr']==0,0.5,data['vr']) 
    data['vr'] = np.where(data['vr']<0,0,data['vr']) 
    data['acend'] = np.multiply(data['Volume'],data['vr']) 

    for i in range(len(data['Open'])):
        if i<19:
            data['Volume Ratio'][i]=0
        else:
            data['Volume Ratio'][i] = ((sum(data['acend'][i-19:i]))/((sum(data['Volume'][i-19:i])-sum(data['acend'][i-19:i]))))*100
   ```

Comment: please consider to edit the title: make it more specific for your problem.

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using conditional row selection and `rolling.sum()`:

```
data.loc[data.index[:20], 'Volume Ratio'] = 0
data.loc[data.index[20:], 'Volume Ratio'] = (data.loc[:20:, 'acend'].rolling(window=20).sum() / (data.loc[:20:, 'Volume'].rolling(window=20).sum() - data.loc[:20:, 'acend'].rolling(window=20).sum()) * 100
```

or, simplified - `.rolling.sum()` will create `np.nan` for the first 20 values so just use `.fillna(0)`:

```
data['new_col'] = data['acend'].rolling(window=20).sum().div(data['Volume'].rolling(window=20).sum().subtract(data['acend'].rolling(window=20).sum()).mul(100).fillna(0)
```